# Named entity graph JOINS results (need distinct option) in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using @NamedEntityGraph annotation to load a graph from database.

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Firma.uredjivanje",
    attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(value="prevodi", subgraph = "prevodi")
    },
    subgraphs = {
            @NamedSubgraph(
                    name = "prevodi",
                    attributeNodes = {
                            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "jezik", subgraph = "jezik")
                    }
            )
    }
)
```

In the Spring Data JPA repository, I'm using annotation:

```
@EntityGraph(value="Firma.uredjivanje", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Firma> getByAktivna(boolean aktivna);
```

Everything works as expected, expect that all relations are joined, and I get duplicate Firma entities (because of JOIN). Instead of a List with entity id's {1,2,3}, I get {1,1,1,2,2,3}.

What is the best way to get distinct entities (if this is not a bug ofcourse).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer... Since NamedEntityGraph does JOIN in database, it selects all entities without DISTINCT. So the solution is to use Distinct in method name...

```
@EntityGraph(value="Firma.uredjivanje", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Firma> getDistinctByAktivna(boolean aktivna);
```

Comment: Dear Sir, you saved my day! Thank you very much for hinting out the "Distinct" KeyWord for method queries!

Answer (score 0):

After adding   `dictinct`    I have error logs during server starup (maybe because there is no such thing as    `findDistinctAll()`    .

For me help a hint in https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-680.

I added    `@Query`    annotation to the method, so my method looks like below

```
@EntityGraph(value = "User.detail", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u")
List<User> findAll();
```

Comment: Don't forget the `@QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false")})` to not send the distinct into the SQL