# JPA 2.1 Entity Graph returns duplicated results

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, entitymanager, wildfly

I started using the new entity graph feature in JPA 2.1 to specify the Lazy collections that must be loaded.
Consider following classes:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="findWithFilterAttr","select a from A a where a.filterAttribute like :filter")
})
@NamedEntityGraphs({
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.childs", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("childs"))})
public class A{
  @Id
  private long id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
  private List<B> childs;
  private String filterAttribute;
}
@Entity
public class B{ 
  @Id
  private long id;
  @ManyToOne
  private A parent;
}
```

When I execute the named query to obtain a list of A entities with the entity graph hint I get a collection with repeated A entities.
How can I load the A entities only once.

I'm using:

- Hibernate 4.3.5
- Wildfly 8.1

Answer (score 6):

I finally solved this, I added DISTINCT to the named query and everything works now.... 
The error was caused because when the JPA Provider find a entity graph hint, it creates a LEFT JOIN with the child table.
Original Query without entity graph:

```
11:55:28,950 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23) Hibernate: 
11:55:28,950 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)     select
11:55:28,951 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)         entitya0_.id as id1_0_0_,
11:55:28,951 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)         childs1_.id as id1_1_1_,
11:55:28,951 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)         entitya0_.filter as filter2_0_0_,
11:55:28,951 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)         childs1_.parent_id as parent_i2_1_1_,
11:55:28,951 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)         childs1_.parent_id as parent_i2_0_0__,
11:55:28,951 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)         childs1_.id as id1_1_0__ 
11:55:28,951 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)     from
11:55:28,951 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)         EntityA entitya0_ 
11:55:28,951 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)     left outer join
11:55:28,952 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)         EntityB childs1_ 
11:55:28,952 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)             on entitya0_.id=childs1_.parent_id 
11:55:28,952 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)     where
11:55:28,952 INFO  [stdout] (default task-23)         entitya0_.filter like ?
```

Query with distinct and entity graph:

```
11:57:25,051 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) Hibernate: 
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)     select
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)         distinct entitya0_.id as id1_0_0_,
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)         childs1_.id as id1_1_1_,
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)         entitya0_.filter as filter2_0_0_,
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)         childs1_.parent_id as parent_i2_1_1_,
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)         childs1_.parent_id as parent_i2_0_0__,
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)         childs1_.id as id1_1_0__ 
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)     from
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)         EntityA entitya0_ 
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)     left outer join
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)         EntityB childs1_ 
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)             on entitya0_.id=childs1_.parent_id 
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)     where
11:57:25,052 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24)         entitya0_.filter like ?
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting your solution! This also works with JPA named Queries. see:
[this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314829/named-entity-graph-joins-results-need-distinct-option)

Comment: can you write how you added distinct to your query?

Answer (score 4):

A small complement.

I had the same problem as you. 
I think this behaviour is unexpected and may be a flaw in hibernate.
It shouldn't be needed to specify `distinct` as it's the case for fetches directly specified in the JPQL query.

Your solution is rather a workaround because of the implementation's limitation.
By checking the code (computation of `needsDistincting` flag in method `list()`, available at [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.5.Final/org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/QueryTranslatorImpl.java#QueryTranslatorImpl.list%28org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor%2Corg.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters%29)), there are 2 solution:

- adding limits to the query
- using distinct

Comment: Note: this is a pure hibernate problem, no Wildfly here. You should remove the tag.