# How to use entity graph in spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I begin to learn to use entity-graph to reduce N+1 problem.but I face a problem that findAll method return duplicate data.

`person`

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long id;
    public String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Department department;
```

`department`

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "department.p",attributeNodes = 
@NamedAttributeNode(value = "people"))
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "department_id")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = 
        CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
```

I create a `departmentrepo`

```
interface DepartmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Department,Long> {

@EntityGraph(value = "department.p", type = 
     EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<Department> findAll();
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

what's wrong about my code? the method `findAll` can not use EntityGraph?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA 2.1 Entity Graph returns duplicated results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170142/jpa-2-1-entity-graph-returns-duplicated-results)

Answer (score 0):

- **Method 1:**

we can use the DISTINCT keyword to remove duplicate data

- **Method 2:**

we can use the set collection. I find that a way to [remove duplicate data](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#jive_content_id_Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword) in hibernate form, and this way give us a reason that why hibernate create duplicate data.